# Exists function within a Case Statement within a Select Statement takes FOREVER

Tags: sql, performance, select, exists, case-when

I commented out the offending code. When I comment this part out, it takes about 5 seconds to run.

With the extra conditions in, it takes about a year (okay like 10 mins).

Thanks for your help guys!

```
SELECT  t.account as fstrAccount,
        t.idno as flngID,
        CASE    
        WHEN t.fstrType = '' THEN '' 

        WHEN wd.fstrWorkType    = 'SUSIN1'
        AND wd.fstrOwner        =  ' ' 
        AND wd.flngworkkey      =  wr.flngworkkey 
        AND wr.fstrAccountType  <> '007' 
        AND wr.fblnOpen         =  1 
        --AND   EXISTS  
        --  (SELECT 1 
        --  FROM    tblIndicator id
        --  WHERE   id.fstrIndicator   = 'EIWTCH' 
        --  AND id.flngVer         = 0 
        --  AND id.flngAccountKey  = wd.flngAccountKey)
        THEN 'Suspended for Audit Indicator - EIC Watch For'
        ELSE    t.fstrTaskSource + '_TYP_' + t.fstrType 
        END AS fstrType,
```

Comment: You probably need to index `tblIndicator.fstrIndicator` or `tblIndicator.flngAccountKey`

Comment: Why not add an additional join (left join) on tblIndicator to the from clause so you don't have to do the sub query and exists.  Otherwise the query has to fire each time instead of once.   add to the left join teh added where clause criteria and then simply check for null on the id.flngaccountkey  but to really know we need to see execution plans and results.

Comment: how should I go about indexing them? any examples, i've never explicitly set out to do that before (beginner)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, EXISTS clause seem to cause poor behaviour on databases, even when it should land on an index -- the complex query just confuses the database optimizer and it ends up re-running the correlated subquery for every row in the main table.

When all other optimization has failed, I usually work around this by rewriting it as a left outer join and checking for NULL on a non-NULL column in the joined table.  That sometimes makes the query understandable by the optimizer, and it does a proper indexed join.

For your SQL, it might look something like:

```
SELECT 
   t.account as fstrAccount,
   t.idno as flngID,
   CASE
      ...
      AND wr.fblnOpen = 1
      AND NOT id.flngVer IS NULL
      ...
FROM
      ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblIndicator id
ON
    id.fstrIndicator = 'EIWTCH'
    AND id.flngVer = 0
    AND id.flngAccountKey = wd.flngAccountKey
```

This assumes that there is at most one "id" for every "wd", using that ON clause.  If there can be more than one match, you can use an aggregate function like MAX() and rely on the fact that the aggregate function will return NULL if there are no records.  In that case "AND NOT id.flngVer IS NULL" becomes "AND NOT MAX(id.flngVer) IS NULL".  If you use an aggregate function, you will also have to add the necessary GROUP BY statement.

Comment: This is a good explanation of why the EXISTS clause can kind of suck. (They can be very expensive)  I would certainly try changing your query before you go trying to change your database, esp if you are a relative beginner.

Answer (score 2):

In order to process the query with the `exists`, the SQL engine needs to evaluate that query.  You don't specify the engine, but most SQL engines are not particularly good at this.  They will cycle through the inner table, `tblIndicator`, for each row.  They might even do this for every row, to get the value before evaluating the `case` statement.

The first way to improve performance is to add an index:

```
create index tblIndicator_fstrIndicator_flngVer_flngAccountKey on
    tblIndicator(fstrIndicator, flngVer, flngAccountKey)
```

The second way to improve performance would be to change this to a `left outer join`.  If at most one row would match, then this is easy.  If you might have multiple matches, then the query would require a bit more work.